# How to test the migration of a domain without actually changing the domain?

Tags: web-hosting, domains, dns, free, migration

I have a somewhat complicated situation. We have a blog let's say at `myblog.com` and it is running fine. However, we now want to cut the budget and use a free hosting service `isgreat.org`. The service allows us to let a domain point to it so that we can host our blog.

The problem is, now I'll have to change the domain's HOST record in order to start testing it. I obviously want a way to test it before actually changing anything. Using an alias for `test.myblog.com` requires the domain to be managed in the service's control panel, which I don't want either.

So, the question is, can I type the IP address of the host in the browser, and somehow tell it that I am referring to it under the domain name `myblog.com`, so that it will show me my blog, instead of a default page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can edit your hosts file in a way that this domain name points to different IP. For example in Windows the host file is in:

`\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\`

In Ubuntu it is in:

`/etc/`

So you find the file, open it with simple text editor, and write the new IP and the domain name. It must look something like:

`92.152.175.86 mydomain.com`

Comment: yes thanks! how can I forget that? BTW you meant "Ubuntu", didn't you?

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac, changing the hosts file is a little tricky, so use the free [Gas Mask](http://www.clockwise.ee/gasmask/) to do this.

Comment: Nice app! I wouldn't class it as "tricky" on the Mac though, in case anyone is wondering it's /etc/hosts and works how you would expect.

Comment: "tricky" may be overstating it, but i think a lot of Mac users don't know how to view hidden files, and this app cuts out that step.